# Trying to pull Etsy collection names onto sheets with ImportXML but it keeps saying Imported content empty

Tags: html, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I put in every single class I could to make it as specific as possible but it still says its empty

```
=index(IMPORTXML("https://www.etsy.com/people/413dgiv4?ref=hdr-fav&tab=items","div[@class='tabbed-nav-container wt-action-group wt-action-group--image fit-width-to-content wt-list-inline wt-flex-nowrap wt-overflow-y-hidden  container-spacing wt-align-items-flex-start']/a[position()>2]/span[@class='wt-p-xs-0 wt-m-xs-0 nav-group-item  nav-profile data-tab-title=']/div[@class='wt-mb-xs-2 wt-display-flex-xs wt-flex-direction-column-xs wt-align-items-center tab-details-container']/div[@class='wt-display-flex-xs wt-align-items-flex-start wt-text-center-xs']//p[@class='wt-text-caption-title wt-text-truncate--multi-line wt-break-word tab-title']"),1)
```

I know I'm able to pull data from it because when I use this code with practically no classes specified

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.etsy.com/people/413dgiv4?ref=hdr-fav&tab=items","//div[@class='tabbed-nav-container wt-action-group wt-action-group--image fit-width-to-content wt-list-inline wt-flex-nowrap wt-overflow-y-hidden  container-spacing wt-align-items-flex-start']/a/span/div/div/p")
```

[And this is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ii4Fd.png)

It's only a few of the collection names, all of these are the ones Etsy makes for you instead of the collections you make yourself. Please help me.

Comment: Can you provide your expected values?

Comment: Sure, here: https://imgur.com/a/eOsQ5D0

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I access your showing URL, unfortunately, I cannot find your provided situation. I apologize for this.